# Docker Postgres - PDO exception get

Tags: postgresql, pdo, docker, docker-compose

I am new with Docker, but I am in trouble, I've get this error always:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in /var/www/html/index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/index.php(16): PDO->__construct('pgsql:host=loca...', 'project', 'project') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 16
```

Here is my index.php:

```
<?php
        $database   = $user = $password = "project";
        $host       = "localhost";
        $connection = new PDO("pgsql:host={$host};dbname={$database};charset=utf8", $user, $password);
        $query      = $connection->query("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'");
        $tables     = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

And this is how my Dockerfile looks:

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y
RUN apt-get install git

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring mcrypt opcache
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/include/postgresql/
RUN docker-php-ext-install pgsql pdo_pgsql

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

However I have that feeling that Dockerfile does not run, it is too fast when I run the `docker-compose up -d` command.

Somebody knows why I get the PDOException?

Comment: `PDOException` is a php exception, so I assume the container starts. Are you sure the driver is installed?

Comment: I am not sure, I do not know how I can check in Docker...

Comment: find the running instance and attach to it. e.g. `docker ps` to find your instance and `docker attach <hash>`, then you need to find out if it installed.

Comment: I used other command, I think yes it is installed. (I checked the filesystem, it is exist - I did not find any specific linux command to check pdo pgsql extension exists or not.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the package is installed, you need to enable the module in php.ini

Add the following line to php.ini file

```
extension=php_pgsql.so
```

Comment: It has been added... I think I switch back to Vagrant, or try to creat new docker configuration.